# Invalid JWT signature on google platform service authentication

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, service-accounts

continuing test with the Cloud Speech API...
I've downloaded another sample from [here](https://github.com/yurifariasg/android-google-speech-sample), and I've slightly modified it because the class ClientAuthInterceptor is deprecated. I'm using a service account, and the relevant used code is this:

```
// This is contained in the MainActivity code.
String fCred = _lu.getBasePath() + "auth.json";

try
{
    InputStream isCred = new FileInputStream(fCred);
    ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(HOSTNAME, PORT).build();
    mStreamingClient = new StreamingRecognizeClient(channel, isCred, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE);
}
catch (IOException openEx)
{
    Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Error", openEx);
}

// This is contained in the StreamingRecognizeClient class code
public StreamingRecognizeClient(ManagedChannel channel, InputStream credentials, int samplingRate) throws IOException
{
    this.mSamplingRate = samplingRate;
    this.mChannel = channel;
    GoogleCredentials creds = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentials);

    if (creds.createScopedRequired())
        creds = creds.createScoped(OAUTH2_SCOPES);

    CallCredentials callCreds = MoreCallCredentials.from(creds);
    mSpeechClient = SpeechGrpc.newStub(channel).withCallCredentials(callCreds);

    credentials.close();
}
```

All this code is called during the app initialization, and the file *auth.json* is the authentication file generated by the Google Console, containing all the info on the project ID and the private key.
Then the function *recognizeBytes* is called with the first chunk of audio data; before sending the actual audio data you have to send a message with only the recognizing configuration, and this is done by this function :

```
private void initializeRecognition() throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
    requestObserver = mSpeechClient.streamingRecognize(this);
    RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setEncoding(AudioEncoding.FLAC).setSampleRate(mSamplingRate).build();
    StreamingRecognitionConfig streamingConfig = StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setConfig(config).setInterimResults(true).setSingleUtterance(true).build();
    StreamingRecognizeRequest initial = StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder().setStreamingConfig(streamingConfig).build();

    requestObserver.onNext(initial);
}
```

After this first call, what I obtain is a 400 error code, as stated by the stack trace below :

```
11-30 15:34:12.916 3676-7309/? W/StreamingRecognizeClient: recognize failed: {0}: Status{code=UNAUTHENTICATED, description=null, cause=java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: }
11-30 15:34:12.918 3676-7309/? E/StreamingRecognizeClient: Error to Recognize.
   io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED
       at me.yurifariasg.StreamingRecognizeClient.onError(StreamingRecognizeClient.java:98)
       at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:395)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:481)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:398)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:513)
       at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:52)
       at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: 
       at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:227)
       at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:97)
       at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:74)
       at io.grpc.auth.GoogleAuthLibraryCallCredentials$1.run(GoogleAuthLibraryCallCredentials.java:113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
   Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
       {
           "error" : "invalid_grant",
           "error_description" : "Invalid JWT Signature."
       }
       at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1054)
       at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:225)
                                                            ... 6 more
```

As all the process of signing the request is performed by the Google library, I don't know exactly what can be done...
I've already sent a request to the Google technical support, available during the trial period, but maybe someone has some advice.

Thanks.
Rodolfo.

Comment: A friend of mine (for whom I posted this question) has finally created a WORKING sample that sends a pre-recorded flac audio file. If anyone is interested i'll ask for the working code. It's a small project in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am uploading symbol files to firebase crash report. After I "generate new private key" at firebase console, then the issue solved. So, did you try to get a new "auth.json"?